# Weird HTML behavior?

Tags: html

```
<a href='#' style='display: block;  border: 1px solid black; width: 208px; height: 210px;'>
    <a href='#'>My link</a> 
</a>
```

Why is it that when I open this html in a browser, it shows me the 'My Link' button outside the box with the black border (that is another link) element?

Comment: I still only see an `<a>` nested within an `<a>`. Invalid HTML is invalid.

Comment: Why do you have nested `<a>` elements?

Comment: Why are you using nested anchor links?  Why, in fact, are you **not** using a `<div>`?

Comment: I don't understand why you put an link inside another one.. which is the logic??

Comment: But what if in my website there really should be a button inside another button, that when clicked takes you to different pages?

Comment: I'm not aware that the concept of "button inside another button" is valid in the first place

Comment: Everything inside an `<a>` is linked. What is the behavior for a link inside a link? Should the outer link or the inner link apply? Or both? The answer is FILE_NOT_FOUND.

Answer (score 2):

The HTML is invalid. An `a` element may not contain another `a` element. You are seeing browser error recovery in action.

Given your code as input, the DOM generated in Chrome looks (when serialized back to HTML) like this:

```
<a href="#" style="display: block;  border: 1px solid black; width: 208px; height: 210px;">
    </a><a href="#">My link</a>
```

I don't have time to write tests to prove it, but I suspect the logic being used to recover is:

1. Second `a` element not allowed here
2. Close first `a` element prematurely so the second one is allowed
3. My Link
4. End of `a` element
5. End tag for `a` element that is not open: discard it

Answer (score 0):

looks fine if you do this:

```
<div style="display: block;  border: 1px solid black; width: 208px; height: 210px;">
<a href="#">My link</a> 
</div>
```